# How to insert two serial numbers with one insert into

Tags: html, mysql, sql, laravel

I try to make it possible to lend two books at once my problem is that only one value gets forwarded. The form looks like this:

[image]

In the view I tried to rename the field to "serial number2" because I thought that he just ignored the second serial number because of the same name.

This is my View:

```
               <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Lend a book') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('borrow.store') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="serialnumber" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Please scan the Serialnumber of the book') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="serialnumber" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('serialnumber') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="serialnumber" value="{{ old('serialnumber') }}" required   @if (Session::has('autofocus')) autofocus @endif>

                                @if ($errors->any())
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">The book is not in stock.
                                        <ul>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="serialnumber" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="serialnumber" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('serialnumber') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="serialnumber" value="{{ old('serialnumber') }}" required   @if (Session::has('autofocus')) autofocus @endif>

                                @if ($errors->any())
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">The book is not in stock..
                                        <ul>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="comment" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('comment') }}</label>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!--                        <input id="ma_id" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('ma_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('ma_id') }}" required> -->
                            <input id="comment" type="text-field" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Test">


                            @if ($errors->has('comment'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback">
                              <strong>{{ $errors->first('comment') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        </div>


                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="ma_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('scan membercard to identify yourself') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
  <!--                        <input id="ma_id" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('ma_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('ma_id') }}" required> -->
                              <input id="ma_id" type="password" class="form-control" name="ma_id" required>


                              @if ($errors->has('ma_id'))
                              <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('ma_id') }}</strong>
                              </span>
                              @endif
                          </div>
                        </div>







                      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('send') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

This is my Controller:

```
  public function store(bookRequest $request)
{

  //if( !book::find($request->get('serialnumber'))->exists() ) {
    $this->middleware('guest');

    request()->validate([
      'serialnumber' => 'required',
      'serialnumber' => 'required',
      'ma_id' => 'required'
    ]);


    book::create($request->all());


    return redirect()->route('book.index');


}
```

There is no error but the problem is that he writes only one serial number into the database as described above and completely ignores the other one that comes into the second field. My question is what I have to adjust so that the second serial number with the same data can be written into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two items with the same name (for example `serialnumber`) in the same form, otherwise only one value is going to be processed. Please check the inspection tool in the browser. If you need multiple inputs with the same "name" append `[]` to the name (for example `name=serialnumber[]`).

More info at [HTML 5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-form-name)

In the other hand, you have multiple items with the same ID. That's another issue to fix in some point.

Once you have your data in the controller you will have to generate your insert data accordingly

```
$requestData = $request->validated();

$data = [
    [
       'serialnumber' => $requestData['serialnumber'][0],
       'comment'      => $requestData['comment'],
       'ma_id'        => $requestData['ma_id']
    ],
    [
       'serialnumber' => $requestData['serialnumber'][1],
       'comment'      => $requestData['comment'],
       'ma_id'        => $requestData['ma_id']
    ]
];

Book::insert($data);
```

Comment: I get this error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in and the follwoing comment: "create" array:1 [▼ 0 => array:5 [▼ "_token" => "NIrq67cB51EJLCQvTsBxLxcII2tpvCbIWkPJxLIT" "serialnumber" => array:2 [▼ 0 => "4004358118100009" 1 => "4002578018100010" ] "comment" => "ma_id" => "0000000003" "index" => "values" ] ]

Comment: You will have to construct the data before using ```book::create($request->all());```

Answer (score 0):

Make input's name as array.

Replace `name="serialnumber"` with `name="serialnumber[]"`. When form is submitted, you will receive an array with both serial numbers.

Comment: I get this error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in and the follwoing comment: 

"create"
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "_token" => "NIrq67cB51EJLCQvTsBxLxcII2tpvCbIWkPJxLIT"
    "serialnumber" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "4004358118100009"
      1 => "4002578018100010"
    ]
    "comment" => 
    "ma_id" => "0000000003"
    "index" => "values"
  ]
]

Comment: Earlier your code was expecting string. Now it's an array due to multiple values. So you have to handle it at the place where the error is occurring.